# iOS 7.1 map is not loading and giving following message

Tags: ios, mapkit

This is the message I'm seeing when trying to load a mapView. My annotations are loading fine but no map, or sometimes a partial map. I get a blank page. but when I pan, some of the map does load.
*edit:: seems to be happening on iPod touch 7.1 - iPhone 5 working ok

> Localization tile 22.50.7 GEOTileSetStyle_VECTOR_POI, GEOTileSize_PX512, GEOTileScale_NODPI.en is not in VLOC format

my code:

```
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];

// get location from search
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = self.searchLat;
zoomLocation.longitude= self.searchLon;

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, self.mapScale*METERS_PER_MILE, self.mapScale*METERS_PER_MILE);
[self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

// remove all previous annotations
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
{
    [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
}

for (int i = 0; i < [self.mapArray count]; i++)
{
    MyInfo *info = [self.mapArray objectAtIndex:i];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = info.lat;
    coord.longitude = info.lon;

    NSInteger count = i+1;
    MyAnnotation *annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord title:info.desc clubInfo:info index:count];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar errors in Xcode 5.0.
Upgrading Xcode to 5.1 solved the issue.